# Line feed regular expression doesn't work in Geany

Tags: regex, geany

I want to detect line feed with [Geany](https://www.geany.org/) in Ubuntu. I used regular expressions such as `\n` , `\r` and `\r\n`, but it doesn't detect anything.

[image]

[image]

There are some line ending settings that I also try to change to make it work, but still no success:

[image]

And finally, I also tried to use different encoding from document → set encoding menu, but still no success.

I guess I am doing something wrong, but I still don't know what.

Comment: Did you try with checking the multi-line check box?

Comment: Besides, did you try `\R`?

Comment: @MohammadYusufGhazi you are right, that was the missing option! tnx

Comment: See http://www.geany.org/manual/current/#multi-line-regular-expressions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [Mohammad Yusuf Ghazi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4082217/mohammad-yusuf-ghazi) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40804360/line-feed-regular-expression-doesnt-in-geany/40807205#comment68829794_40804360), you need to enable the *Use multi-line matching* option. See the [Geany docs](http://www.geany.org/manual/current/#multi-line-regular-expressions):

> The *Use multi-line matching* dialog option enables multi-line regular expressions.
>   
>   Multi-line regular expressions work just like single-line ones but a match can span several lines.

Besides, you may also use [`\R` shorthand class for any line break sequence](http://www.geany.org/manual/gtk/glib/glib-regex-syntax.html#idp5496176):

> **Newline sequences**
>   Outside a character class, the escape sequence \R matches any Unicode newline sequence. This particular group matches either the two-character sequence CR followed by LF, or one of the single characters LF (linefeed, U+000A), VT (vertical tab, U+000B), FF (formfeed, U+000C), CR (carriage return, U+000D), NEL (next line, U+0085), LS (line separator, U+2028), or PS (paragraph separator, U+2029). The two-character sequence is treated as a single unit that cannot be split. Inside a character class, \R matches the letter "R".

Answer (score 0):

In a simple search just within the open file, select from the end of the line to the beginning of the first line. Copy and paste in the find box.

It will be seen as a squarebox with four letters written inside. This will definitely detect each LF in Geany.

In regex, use `$` instead of `\r\n` or `\R`. It will detect the end of line in multiline mode in Geany.